# acedEntSelでプロンプトに表示させない方法

Tags: ijcad, arx

```
acedEntSel(_T(""), name, pnt)
```

AutoCADでは上記のようにするとプロンプト表示はなくなりますが、
IJCADではデフォルトの文字列が出力されます。
これをAutoCADのようにプロンプトへの出力がないようにできないでしょうか？

ちなみにacedGetPointなどはAutoCADと同じようにプロンプトへの出力をなくせるようです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

同じコーディングではできないみたいですね。
次のようにすれば一応メッセージは表示されなくなりましたが・・・

acedEntSel(_T("\r"), name, pnt)

場合によっては入力後に改行出力が必要かもしれません。